# Object is not a function - IONIC 3 Facebook Login

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I am working on an IONIC 3 application, and trying to make login using Facebook. I have made a button, where I trigger a `registerUser()` function on `click` event. I have perfectly created app over Facebook developer console, and installed Facebook plugin through [this](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/facebook/) link. I followed the documentation, and it worked perfectly.

I have imported `import { Facebook } from '@ionic-native/facebook/ngx';` in the `app.module.ts` file, and assigned `Facebook` in the Providers as well. And also Imported `import { Facebook, FacebookLoginResponse } from '@ionic-native/facebook/ngx';` in the `signup.ts`.

The problem is, this app was built with IONIC 3, and now when I flip to the documentation of [IONIC 3](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/), and search for facebook, upon clicking the facebook link, I get redirected to [this](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/facebook/) page which I followed to install the plugins etc. When I run the app, the function `registerUser()` is triggered and it returns an error which says,

```js
ERROR TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at Facebook.login (index.js:62)
    at SignupPage.webpackJsonp.186.SignupPage.registerUser (signup.ts:83)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (SignupPage.html:78)
    at handleEvent (core.js:13589)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:15098)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:14685)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:10004)
    at core.js:10629
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:2628)
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
```

**The Facebook Code**

```js
export class SignupPage {
  constructor(
    public facebook: Facebook
  ) {}
  
  //Register User
  registerUser() {
    this.facebook.login(['public_profile', 'user_friends', 'email'])
      .then((res: FacebookLoginResponse) => {
        console.log('Logged into Facebook!', res)
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log('Error logging into Facebook', e)
      });
  }
}
```

**The IONIC Button**

```js
      <ion-item id="border-none">
        <button ion-button block id="login-button" (click)="registerUser()">Create Account</button>
      </ion-item>
```

> I have searched for different solutions, even here, but nothing helped out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

/ngx extention is for ionic 4 onwards, it won't work for ionic 3 and and will throw that

TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

so i suggest you to go with V3 docs and implement that for ionic 3 project 
https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/facebook/

Comment: So can infer that I cannot use Facebook5 in ionic3?